# Is it possible to specify in Eclipse managed projects the path of a library independent of configuration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.5

Within Properties/Settings/Tool Settings, one can specify a Library search path (-L).

For a specific build configuration one can enter

${workspace_loc:/SomeLib/Debug} or ${workspace_loc:/SomeLib/Release}

depending on the configuration.

Is there a variable, like ${workspace_loc} that can be used specify a 'universal' search path. This path would then be correct regardless of the configuration.

Such as:

${workspace_loc:/SomeLib/${config}}

BTW, Is the Eclipse documentation showing a list of all the workspace/project variables?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create you own **string substitution**. "You can create and configure simple launch variables which you can reference in launch configurations that support variables".This is done under "Preferences">"Run/Debug">"String Substitution".

As far as list of possible variables goes, I found that if you go to "Run Configurations" and select "Arguments" tab then click on "Variables..." button - you'll get a window with all variables and their descriptions. You can even edit string substitutions from there.

Hope it helped.